# BULK INSERT not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bulk-insert

I have a text file, which I want to insert into a table in my database.

My query looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT myDepartment
FROM 'C:\myDepartment-c-t.txt'
WITH (
  DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', -- default terminator
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

On executing it, SQL Server Management Studio 2008 gives the following error:

```
'BULK' rowset provider not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

I googled it and found that SQL Server 2008 *does* support `BULK INSERT`. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> 'BULK' rowset provider not supported in this version of SQL Server.
> ```

`BULK INSERT` is not supported on SQL Azure. You can use `bcp` or write something that wraps `SqlBulkCopy` to bulk insert into SQL Azure. There's other ways to bulk insert aside from these, too.

> On executing it,my SQL management studio 2008,gives the following error :

Don't confuse SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server Database Engine.

Answer (score 0):

BCP is one way to go.

I've actually used the method stated here: Bulk insert with Azure SQL.

Basically you bulk insert your data to a local MSSQL database (which is supported). Create a txt file with all data and bulk insert it into your azure table by using the BCP command in command prompt.